# Complex type resolution in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface, alias

I have a very complex type defined in my Typescript:

```js
export type DraftCamp = DeepPartial<CampForm> & {
  isActive: false
} & FilesExtension
```

Which actually is just an interface with some nested values - no unions. Is there anyway to take a peek into this type and see how it actually looks like? Can I do this without manually following all the other types it references?

Comment: You mean something like expand out the type to see all members ?

Comment: Exactly something like that

Comment: Well, I have good news below 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `Id` type that maps over the intersection. There is no guarantee as to what will expand out a mapped type, but this type **currently** does the trick:

```
type Id<T> = {} & {
  [P in keyof T]: Id<T[P]>
}
```

Using `Id` on an intersection will flatten it out:

```
type FilesExtension = {
  ext: string
}

// Naive implementation, just filler
type DeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>
}

type CampForm = {
  foo: {
    bar: string
  }
  baz: {
    bars: string[]
  }
}

type Id<T> = {} & {
  [P in keyof T]: Id<T[P]>
}
export type DraftCamp = Id<DeepPartial<CampForm> & {
  isActive: false
} & FilesExtension>
// Hover over DraftCamp and you will see the expanded version of it:
// type DraftCamp = {
//     foo?: {
//         bar?: string | undefined;
//     } | undefined;
//     baz?: {
//         bars?: (string | undefined)[] | undefined;
//     } | undefined;
//     isActive: false;
//     ext: string;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=36&ssc=5&pln=26&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgGwgZwKIA9gQHbLge2ygF4oBvAKCigkwC4plgAnObAcwoF8KKB6PlAByAQzgA3aHAC2YJNJzARwAtgA0UAFYBXJlABmiJMwqhIUACIQIYAAojmKkQgA8AFQB8JclSgBtWyg2KABrCBB8fSg3AF0AfgYrG3tHOGd3AJiPbl4zaABhEVkYfGZpb0pqfXx8BkrqKAAjBwYmVg5fHmpmgC86326HZFaWNnY-GM6c03BoAEkAE3cvUjIuKAAyH2oAoKIwiKjYhkWM2yyc2jBS4Cg8y2YRfWBC2W9TpLsHJ1dXsBKyl4tvU4MgAIIAYxUkgY+mcyAg3E2sEQKAwWFwqmy-EEAAl8JJmFACRAiRZHs8-lARNgFlAItooAB3IyMax3AAW0CuNIWEDphLwhGJUTgwDoOLusweTxeRTAFUlDQMNQSPgEys1zWYaraYygAB8oNpaRBDNh+QBuJUNdZGk1881Wm2DHpqygazUNbXINUACj1HENxtNToWAEoJsGHWa2M7Pbbo6G4wtrQnqKDIdCILD4RA04JlbRxYxRhwC1AeEA)

Note: I have to warn you, there are some arcane assignability rules that differ between an intersection and a flattened out type with the same members, but it does mostly work the same. The idea is that `Id` is much like a `console.log` useful for debugging, but don't leave it lying around in production code

Comment: That's so cool :)

I have a problem though with Intellij I'm using - when I want to see expanded version of it in the Intellij using it's feature 'Type info' (ctrl + shift + p) it doesn't expand nested fields.

Comment: Also, is there a way to dump such an extension to a text file, ie. for documentation purposes?

Comment: @Hyster no way to dump it to file, I usually use VSCode or the playground and there you get the full expanded version in  the tool-tip and you can copy it from there ..if you are quick enough :)